# VSCode Python debugger no longer stopping at breakpoints after moving project directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I just moved my project to a new directory on my computer. The debug config executes but no longer stops at breakpoints.

When I move the project folder back to its original location, it's working again.

Thanks for your help!

My launch.json file:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Module Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "module": "bin.main",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Config :

- MacOS 10.15
- VSCode 1.69.2
- Conda virtual env with python 3.7.13
- python extension ms-python.python-2022.13.12381007

Comment: go to the debug bar and hover over the breakpoint, most likely it has a full path of the line to break on

Comment: Just to be sure, the breakpoints were created via VSCode, not using Python `breakpoint()`, right?

Comment: @wjandrea, yes breakpoints were created in VS by left-clicking next to line numbers.

Comment: @riov8, the paths are like "~/Desktop/..." and not "/Users/$username/Desktop/..."

Comment: @rioV8, however it's working fine in my previous folder location with "~/..." (just checked to compare)

Comment: if the breakpoints path are not relative to your workspace why do you think it should still work if you move the workspace, how difficult is it to assign the same breakpoints in the new location

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The paths are correct when I hover the breakpoints. Breakpoints directly created in the new location do not work either.

Comment: Can you provide part of the code with the problem to reproduce the problem

Comment: I guess the problem is not the code but something in VSCode since breakpoints with the same code are working when launched from another directory. So I don't know what other information I can provide.